# Given X_1,...,X_n iid, compute the probability that X iid is less than the k-th order statistic

Tags: probability, independence, order-statistics

I have $n+1$ i.i.d. RV $X_1,\dots,X_n,X$. I compute the order statistics of $X_1,\dots,X_n$:

$$X_{(1)},\dots,X_{(n)}$$

[I'm reading a paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/2107.07511) which says that $P(X \leq X_{(k)})=\frac{k}{n+1}$ (see Appendix 1, theorem A.1). How can I prove it? For the sake of simplicity, it's ok to assume that there are no ties, or that the $X_i$ are continuous RV (which implies that there are no ties with probability 1).

As a start, I tried to compute $P(X \leq X_{(1)})$:

$$P(X \leq X_{(1)})=P(X \leq X_1,\dots,X\leq X_n)=P(X \leq X_1)\dots P(X\leq X_n)$$

because of independence. Now, since $X_1,\dots,X_n,X$ are i.d., I just need to compute $P(X \leq X_1)$: denoting with $f(x), F(x)$ respectively the pdf and the CDF of $X$, this is

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{x_1}p(x,x_1)dxdx_1=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{x_1}f(x)f(x_1)dxdx_1=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x_1)\left(\int_{-\infty}^{x_1}f(x)dx\right)dx_1=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x_1)F(x_1)dx_1=[F(x)F(x)]_{-\infty}^{\infty}-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x_1)F(x_1)dx_1=1-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x_1)F(x_1)dx_1\implies\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{x_1}p(x,x_1)dxdx_1=\frac12$$

Thus, I would have that

$$P(X \leq X_{(1)})=P(X \leq X_1,\dots,X\leq X_n)=P(X \leq X_1)\dots P(X\leq X_n)=\frac{1}{2^n}$$

which is clearly not what the paper claims. Where did I go wrong, and what is the correct proof?

Comment: $X\le X_i$ are not independent...

Comment: Assuming ties have probability $0$, there is a simple combinatorial argument: there are $(n+1)!$ equally likely possible orderings of $X_1,\dots,X_n,X$; so $X$ is equally likely to be in any of the $n+1$ positions overall; so $X$ is one of the smallest $k$ values with probability $\frac{k}{n+1}$; so $P(X \leq X_{(k)})=\frac{k}{n+1}$

Comment: @DeltaIV Suppose $X,X_1,X_2$ are all $0$ or $1$ with probability $1/2$ (that is, they are Bernoulli). and independent. Then $P(X\le X_1)P(X\le X_2) = (3/4)^2$, but $P(X\le X_1, X\le X_2) = 5/8$

Comment: @DeltaIV there was the same random variable $X$ in different events. In general, it is a sign that things are not independents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Requested from comments:*

As Exodd commented, the events $X\le X_i$ are not independent, so you cannot take the product of their probabilities.

Assuming ties have probability $0$, there is a simple combinatorial argument to answer your question:

- there are $(n+1)!$ equally likely possible orderings of $X_1,\ldots,X_n,X$;
- so $X$ is equally likely to be in any of the $n+1$ positions overall;
- so $X$ is one of the smallest $k$ values with probability $\frac{k}{n+1}$;
- so $P(X \leq X_{(k)})=\frac{k}{n+1}$.

Comment: I'll add a small note for myself. To prove that $P(X = X_{(i)})=\frac{1}{n+1}\ \forall i$, one can note that each position is realized through $n!$ distinct permutations, each one having $p=\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\implies P(X = X_{(i)})=\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}=\frac{1}{n+1}$ Q.E.D.